# PHPPowerPoint generating Tables and Graphs within the PPT

Tags: php, graph, powerpoint

I am using PHPPowerPoint to generate PPT files from PHP and it visually does the job very well, I am looking for a way of generating tables and graphs that are editable within the powerpoint program.

I anyone can help or lead me towards a linux/php binary/class that can accomplish this i would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of PHPPowerpoint handles this functionality:

http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/52225